# Decomposing and reconstructing a harborth graph

Tags: library

I am new with optimization problems.

Does anyone know of a Java or C# library that can be used to decompose and re-construct a [Harborth graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarborthGraph.html) (or any arbitrary graph)?